# EF6 re-scaffold initial migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, npgsql

Please help me with one inconvenience in ef6 migrations.
I change my model very often(because I don't have complete understanding of schema).
I have two migration:
1. Initial (ef6 generates this migration by my model)
2. AddtionalInit (some manual sql code that need to be executed after initialization)

When I change my model I want to re-scaffold Initial migration to apply changes. I migrate to -TargetMigration:0 and try to execute:

```
add-migration Initial -force
```

but it throw with error

```
Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201709290630180_Initial, 201709290631135_AdditionalInit]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration
```

Can I re-scaffold Initial migration without deleting AdditionalInit migration?

P.S. Sorry for English.

Answer (score 0):

You only can re-scaffold the latest migration.
You should delete the migrations after your `Initial` migration keeping somewhere the code you manually added. Then re-scaffold and after that re-add your manual code.

Comment: it is very inconvenient. Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could  use the seed method with Raw SQL to apply any additional schema changes.  You'd have to setup that Raw SQL to do a 'check' to make sure it's changes haven't already been applied before running, because the seed method runs each time the app starts.

Probably best to move it in it's own migration once your model changes are stable, but this is an alternative that would work if you had tons of migration changes while in development.